# Why GET response return 404 error with node server js?

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, express

I created a `server.js` with `node js` . Using `Index.html` i am linking css , js scripts . But after executing HTML file , I am getting 404 errors with respect to that files . But these script files is already present there in that path . I think my server code may be the problem .

This is that **Directory structure :**

ui ( folder ) - inside that - bootstrap , files ( folder )

```
server.js 
ui         --- bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css
           --- files/css/myedited.min.css
           --- files/css/skins/skin-blue.min.css
```

and inside **index.html** i am linking all css/js files .

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Start</title>
  <!-- Tell the browser to be responsive to screen width -->
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
  <!-- Bootstrap 3.3.6 -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/ui/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- Font Awesome -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <!-- Ionicons -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css">
  <!-- Theme style -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/ui/files/css/myedited.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/ui/files/css/skins/skin-blue.min.css">
</head>
```

This is my **server code** :

```
var express = require('express');
var morgan = require('morgan');
var path = require('path');

var app = express();
app.use(morgan('combined'));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'ui', 'index.html'));
});

app.get('/ui/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'ui/bootstrap/css', 'bootstrap.min.css'));
});

app.get('/ui/files/css/skins/skin-blue.min.css', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'ui/files/css/skins', 'skin-blue.min.css'));
});

app.get('/ui/files/css/myedited.min.css', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'ui/files/css', 'myedited.min.css'));
});

var port = 8080; // Use 8080 for local development because you might already have apache running on 80
app.listen(8080, function () {
  console.log(`my app listening on port ${port}!`);
});
```

when i load my application , `index.html` is working fine . With the help of inspect element in browser  , i can see  **response** that

```
Cannot GET /ui/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css
Cannot GET /ui/files/css/myedited.min.css
Cannot GET /ui/dist/files/skins/skin-blue.min.css
```

i also `restarted server` nothing is working . any idea ?

Comment: Most of that code is unnecessary, since you can [serve static files with express](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html). `app.use('/ui', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'ui')));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By placing a `/` at the start of your file paths, you are saying to look for them in the computer base dir, not the current one.

Just remove the `/`:

```
app.get('ui/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'ui/bootstrap/css', 'bootstrap.min.css'));
});

app.get('ui/files/css/skins/skin-blue.min.css', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'ui/files/css/skins', 'skin-blue.min.css'));
});

app.get('ui/files/css/myedited.min.css', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'ui/files/css', 'myedited.min.css'));
});
```

Comment: should i Just remove leading slashes  `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/ui/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">` here also ?